# Liferay: Issue when Using JSON WebService and https

Tags: json, liferay, liferay-6

I have created a Liferay Web Service and made it accessible via JSON.
I call successfully call and use the JSON WebService using this URL:

https://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/my-portlet-name/my-method/time-unit/HOUR/class-name/TEST

I have annotated my Web Services like this:

```
@com.liferay.portal.security.ac.AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled = true, hostAllowedValidationEnabled = false)
```

When I am using this call locally (http) I have no problems.
As soon as I deploy it to our test server (https) I do get "Forbidden - no permissions to access this resource".

**What can I do to access my JSON Web Service calls ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, honestly : I don´t know if there is an answer for that ;)

I have used the Liferay.Service js call to do the same and it works.

So no more URL calling from jQuery ...